# Error compiling tweak in theos

Tags: ios, objective-c-2.0, cydia, tweak

I set a simple tweak using theos following the tutorial [here](http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-your-first-tweak/). However when I run make with the headers from [here](https://github.com/Fr0stDev/SpringBoard-iOS5-Headers), I get

```
Making all for tweak WelcomeWagon...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
/opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:7:26: error: UIApplication.h: No such file or directory
cc1objplus: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/UIApplicationDelegate-Protocol.h:7,
                 from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:9,
                 from Tweak.xm:1:
/opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/NSObject-Protocol.h:7: warning: duplicate declaration for protocol ‘NSObject’
In file included from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:9,
                 from Tweak.xm:1:
/opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/UIApplicationDelegate-Protocol.h:11: warning: duplicate declaration for protocol ‘UIApplicationDelegate’
/opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/UIApplicationDelegate-Protocol.h:35: error: duplicate property declaration ‘window’
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [WelcomeWagon.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

After some searching around I also found that some people were using Ryan Petrich's dumped headers, so I emptied the include folder and put his headers in and ran make, with this as the output

```
Making all for tweak WelcomeWagon...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/QuartzCore-Structs.h:11,
                 from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/CAValueFunction.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:30,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIKit-Structs.h:15,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.h:6,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:12,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /opt/theos//Prefix.pch:4,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/opt/theos//include/IOSurface/IOSurface.h:20:36: error: IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /opt/theos//include/IOSurface/IOSurface.h:21,
                 from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/QuartzCore-Structs.h:11,
                 from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/CAValueFunction.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:30,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIKit-Structs.h:15,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.h:6,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:12,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /opt/theos//Prefix.pch:4,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/opt/theos//include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAccelerator.h:20: error: ‘IOSurfaceRef’ has not been declared
/opt/theos//include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAccelerator.h:20: error: ‘IOSurfaceRef’ has not been declared
In file included from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/QuartzCore-Structs.h:11,
                 from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/CAValueFunction.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:30,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIKit-Structs.h:15,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.h:6,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:12,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /opt/theos//Prefix.pch:4,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/opt/theos//include/IOSurface/IOSurface.h:27: error: variable or field ‘IOSurfaceFlushProcessorCaches’ declared void
/opt/theos//include/IOSurface/IOSurface.h:27: error: ‘IOSurfaceRef’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from /opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/CAValueFunction.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:30,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIKit-Structs.h:15,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.h:6,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:11,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:12,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10,
                 from /opt/theos//Prefix.pch:4,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/opt/theos//include/QuartzCore/QuartzCore-Structs.h:196: error: ‘IOSurfaceRef’ does not name a type
In file included from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIKit2.h:52,
                 from /opt/theos//include/MessageUI/MessageUI-Structs.h:8,
                 from /opt/theos//include/MessageUI/ComposeRecipient.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/ChatKit/CKMailComposeRecipient.h:6,
                 from /opt/theos//include/ChatKit/ChatKit.h:41,
                 from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:13,
                 from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:8,
                 from Tweak.xm:1:
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:85: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:85: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:85: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:86: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:86: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:86: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:91: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:91: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIImage2.h:91: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
In file included from /opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIKit2.h:448,
                 from /opt/theos//include/MessageUI/MessageUI-Structs.h:8,
                 from /opt/theos//include/MessageUI/ComposeRecipient.h:9,
                 from /opt/theos//include/ChatKit/CKMailComposeRecipient.h:6,
                 from /opt/theos//include/ChatKit/ChatKit.h:41,
                 from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:13,
                 from /opt/theos//include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:8,
                 from Tweak.xm:1:
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:19: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:19: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:19: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:20: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:20: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:20: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:21: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:21: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:21: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:116: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:116: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:116: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:117: error: expected type-specifier before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:117: error: expected `)' before ‘IOSurfaceRef’
/opt/theos//include/UIKit/UIWindow2.h:117: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [WelcomeWagon.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I found the same problem with current version of Ryan Petrich's dumped headers today.

Finally I find out that the solution is,

1. Import the dumped Springboard headers
2. Copy /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceAPI.h to /opt/theos/include/IOSurface. The reason is in IOSurface/IOSurface.h!
3. If you are running OS X Lion or later, you may need to comment out the following lines in /opt/theos/include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h:

```
    /* This call lets you get an xpcobject_t that holds a reference to the IOSurface.
    Note: Any live XPC objects created from an IOSurfaceRef implicity increase the IOSurface's global use
    count by one until the object is destroyed. */
    // xpc_object_t IOSurfaceCreateXPCObject(IOSurfaceRef aSurface)
    // IOSFC_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_NA);

    /* This call lets you take an xpcobject_t created via IOSurfaceCreatePort() and recreate an IOSurfaceRef from it. */
    // IOSurfaceRef IOSurfaceLookupFromXPCObject(xpc_object_t xobj)
    // IOSFC_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_NA);
```

Give it a try!

Comment: how do you import the dumped headers?

Comment: how to import dumped headers

Answer (score 2):

I just did this today 02/13/2013 and found the above to be somewhat helpful. With a little brains and the help of Google I found that what you need to do is :

1.) Get the headers - use a Google search for "Ryan Petrich's dumped headers" which will lead you to :https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders

2.) Use git to clone the repo : git clone https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders

3.) run make ( I found that I needed to run make as sudo make due to the location of theos being installed under /opt. )

4.) For each "error file not found" I copied the include files into my project.

5.) I believe you should end up with the following folders in your project folder : 
    AccountSettings     IOKit           SpringBoard
    ActorKit        IOSurface       TelephonyUI
    AppSupport      JavaScriptCore      Tutorial.plist
    Availability2.h     MIME            Tweak.xm
    ChatKit         Makefile        Tweak.xm.original
    CoreFoundation      MediaPlayer     UIKit
    CoreGraphics        Message         WebCore
    DAVKit          MessageUI       WebKit
    DataAccess      MusicLibrary        control
    Foundation      PhotoLibrary        obj
    GraphicsServices    QuartzCore      theos

6.) You need to do #2 from the answer above "Copy /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceAPI.h to /opt/theos/include/IOSurface. The reason is in IOSurface/IOSurface.h!"

7.) You also need to make the edit from the answer above "If you are running OS X Lion, you may need to comment out the following lines in /opt/theos/include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h:"

```
/* This call lets you get an xpcobject_t that holds a reference to the IOSurface.
Note: Any live XPC objects created from an IOSurfaceRef implicity increase the IOSurface's global use
count by one until the object is destroyed. */
// xpc_object_t IOSurfaceCreateXPCObject(IOSurfaceRef aSurface)
// IOSFC_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_NA);

/* This call lets you take an xpcobject_t created via IOSurfaceCreatePort() and recreate an IOSurfaceRef from it. */
// IOSurfaceRef IOSurfaceLookupFromXPCObject(xpc_object_t xobj)
// IOSFC_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_NA);
```

FYI in my IOSurfaceAPI.h these were lines around line number 252/253

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import the dumped Springboard headers.