# Trying to learn iPhone Tweak Dev, unknown Theos error on 'make' command

Tags: ios, makefile, cydia, tweak, theos

This is what comes up in terminal. Any advice? I've done the advice in this thread: [Error compiling tweak in theos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891846/error-compiling-tweak-in-theos) yet it didn't help.

```
Copying resource directories into the application wrapper...
Compiling main.m...
Compiling fooProjectApplication.mm...
Compiling RootViewController.mm...
Linking application fooProject...
collect2: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abort trap: 6]
ld(2090,0x7fff77045960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fcaaa5009c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
collect2: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abort trap: 6]
ld(2094,0x7fff77045960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbeeb6003d0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/nl/nffpk84n2vq1pg2lxcplx4mh0000gn/T//ccKO4deH.out (No such file or directory)
make[2]: *** [obj/fooProject.app/fooProject.ba964c90.unsigned] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-application-all_] Error 2
make: *** [fooProject.all.application.variables] Error 2
```

Comment: The toolchain you have on your device is buggy: specifically, the linker has a memory management bug. What toolchain do you have?

Comment: How would I go about checking this? Sorry, still really new to this.

Comment: you don't "check it", you know what toolchain **you** have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this on the top of your makefile

```
export ARCHS = armv7
export TARGET = iphone:latest:4.3
export GO_EASY_ON_ME=1
```

I kind of had the same problem so this might help you fix it

Comment: This worked but do you mind explaining how/why? Does this set the compatible SDKVERSION to 4.3? Thanks

Comment: Actually I'm rather confused myself. I think its to do with the latest Xcode libraries, as it drops support for  armv6. But about setting the target to 4.3, I honestly have no idea.