# finding IOSurface headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, tweak, theos

I'm getting this error when I try to compile my tweak.

```
'IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h' file not found
#include <IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h>
```

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11492825/754604), but I can't find `/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers` on my computer. I'm running osx 10.9.1. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, not sure about the version it comes from:
http://ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux.googlecode.com/files/IOSurfaceAPI.h